# Is there a terminal command to keep apps from quitting?

Tags: terminal

In macOS Terminal.app how can I issue a command similar to `caffeinate` that keeps all running applications from quitting?

In my System Preferences I have Energy Saver to: computer sleep-never and Display sleep-never, I even have `caffeinate` issued in the terminal.

After a while of no keyboard or mouse activity the screen will go to login mode. All apps like Excel and Mail have quit except those that required a save.

Even Terminal is asking if I really want to quit. I want all to be as if I were touching my keyboard every few minutes so not even the login screen shows and Excel never quits.

Comment: What is your exact scenario? Why don't you want your apps to quit, and what's making them do so?

Comment: Apps aren't supposed to "quit" normally. In what way are they "quitting"?

Comment: I could be wrong, but this seems like a classic case of: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: In my system prefs I have energy saver to: computer sleep-never and Display sleep-never, I even have caffeinate issued in the terminal.  After a while of no keyboard or mouse activity the screen will go to login mode. All apps like Excel and Mail have quit except those that required a save.  Even terminal is asking if I really want to quit.  I want all to be as if I were touching my keyboard every few minutes so not even the login screen shows and excel never quits.

Comment: I have had several Mac Minis running information screens for weeks and months on end, never shutting down or closing apps except during power failures. When the power comes back, the "Start up automatically after a power failure" setting in the Energy Saver System Preferences works as advertized. The root cause of your problem needs to be discovered, not a solution that bypasses what happens. I agree that William T Froggard's XY problem mention is at work here. In Energy Saver, do you have any settings enabled in the Schedule... module?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`screen`](http://ss64.com/osx/screen.html) terminal window manager and its detach feature. This command is installed by default on OS X.

Example scenario.

- Open a terminal
- Run `screen`
- Run a program of your choice e.g. `htop`.
- Suspend this program (Ctrl+z) and run it in background `bg`
- Detach your current session (Ctrl+a d)
- Exit your session and exit the terminal
- Open the terminal again
- List running session with `screen -ls`
- Go back to your session with `screen -r <session id>`
- Use your program again with `fg`

Comment: Despite the no comment downvote, this works well. It maybe seems complicated but if you are used to terminal manipulation, it's not.

Comment: I suspect the down vote was because the answer addresses command line processes and not graphical applications.

Comment: @Graham Miln But the question says :  `In macOS Terminal.app how can I issue a command....`, there is something I don't understand.

Comment: The original question has since been extended with comments that talk about the behaviour of Mail.app and Excel.app – both graphical applications. I believe the desire is for something like `caffeinate`, a command line tool, that will affect macOS graphical applications. `screen` is a great tool but not quite what this questioner seems to want.